# Converting JSON key - value pair into Java object using Retrofit when one of the key in json contains a list of values

Tags: java, android, json, serialization, retrofit2

I am learning to make API calls in Android through Retrofit and got stuck due to JSON to java object conversion using retrofit library. I have explained the issue in detail as below. If anyone can help, it would be really grateful.

I have the following JSON as a response from my API ---

```
[
  {
   "key1": "value1",
   "key2": "value2",
   "key3": "["v1", "v2", "v3"]"
  }
]
```

In android environment, I am using retrofit to make calls to the API.
I made the following POJO  ----

```
public class apiResponsePOJO implements Serializable {
    @SerializedName("key1")
    @Expose
    private String key1;

    @SerializedName("key2")
    @Expose
    private String key2;

    @SerializedName("key3")
    @Expose
    private List<String> key3;

    // I have created the getter and setter methods for all the three attributes.
}
```

The APIInterface class contains the following GET method definition --

```
    @GET("attribute/")
    Call<apiResponsePojo> getAttribute(@Query("attributeID") Integer attributeID);
```

I am calling the API Interface in one of the Fragment Class as follows --

```
    APIInterface apiInterface = APIClient.getClient(url).create(APIInterface.class);
    getAttributeDetails(attributeID);
```

The definition for getAttributeDetails method is as follows --

```
public void getAttributeDetails(int attributeID) {
        Call<apiResponsePOJO> call = apiInterface.getAttribute(attributeID);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<apiResponsePOJO>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<apiResponsePOJO> call, Response<apiResponsePOJO> response) {
                apiResponseDetails = response.body();

                Log.e("Server", "response = " + apiResponseDetails.getValue1());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<apiResponsePOJO> call, Throwable t) {

                Log.e("Server", t.getMessage());
//              t.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
```

**The error I am receiving is:  Unterminated object at line 15 column 20 path $.key3**

Can Someone explain to me why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

your response is on wrong format, key3 is a JSONArray so no quotation mark

it should be :

`[
  {
   "key1": "value1",
   "key2": "value2",
   "key3": ["v1", "v2", "v3"]
  }
]`

Comment: The output that I was receiving before `"["v1", "v2", "v3"]"` was from the API. I needed to change the API response from  `"["v1", "v2", "v3"]"` to `["v1", "v2", "v3"]` which is what you mentioned above and it worked perfectly. Thank you very much.